# AWS: containarised serverless solutions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, containers, autoscaling, serverless

This is more of an architectural question. If I should be asking this question elsewhere, please let me know and I shall.

I have a use-case where I need to run the same `python` script (could be long-running) multiple times based on demand and pass on different parameters to each of them. The trigger for running the script is external and it should be able to pass on a STRING parameter to the script along with the resource configurations each script requires to run. We plan to start using AWS by next month and I was going through the various options I have. `AWS Batch` and `Fargate` both seem like feasible options given my requirements of not having to manage the infrastructure, dynamic spawning of jobs and management of jobs via `python SDK`.

The only problem is that both of these services are not available in India. I need to have my processing servers in India physically. What options do I have? Auto-scaling and Python SDK management (Creation and Deletion of tasks) are my main requirements (preferably containerized).

Comment: Have you gone through https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you restricted to India? Often restrictions are due to data retention, in which case just store your data on Indian servers (S3, DynamoDB etc) and then you are able to run your 'program' in another AWS region